# Retrieve posts by page in wp rest api

Tags: rest-api

I want to develop an app for my WordPress.org website. I am using wp rest api to receive post in json. My question is how do I retrieve posts page by page. For example if there are 50 posts I want to receive 1-10 then 11-20 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can add `?page={$page_number}` to the URL that you're requesting.

See, for example, http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=2.

It appears to split the posts into pages of 10.

### Reference

- [WP-API documentation](http://wp-api.org/guides/working-with-posts.html#collection-views) (I found this in the docs for v1 of the API, but per the sample URL above, it works on v2 as well)